# Update a previous version of plugin when the new plugin is built from the scratch

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, updates, automatic-updates

I'm seeking help and suggestion from all of you. I've built a plugin from the scratch and now instructed to update the previous version of that plugin. But the new version that I've created is totally different from the previous version. The name of the files, folders, project structure and database(I've created few tables not using anything from the old) even the text-domain is changed. I've searched through the internet to see how update works and found wordpress maintains a svn repository and maintain a tag folder for versions. But I'm not sure if everything is changed will that work. What should I be concerned about updating a previous version of a plugin. I'm looking for you kind advice or solution here what would be the best for me in this situation so that the users can see a new version comes in and a single click will update their previous version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your plugin in the WP Repository, and

- change the version number in the readme.txt file
- put the new code in a new 'tags' folder with the version as the folder name
- also put the new code in the root of your repository (and I also put it in the 'trunk' folder
- and do the SVN Update thing

Then anyone with the plugin installed will get a notice about the update via the Admin, Update screen. And updating it will get the latest version installed on their WP system.

I'd put some sort of notice on the Settings screen about the new version, in addition to the needed information in the readme.txt file , which is used to display text on the various pages on your WP plugin page.

Comment: Rick thank you so much. I'll give it a try and if everything goes fine then I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Rick I did all the things that you said. Created versions in Tag folder. Put everything from trunk to tag. Also changed the stable tag in trunk/readme.txt and put all the code in the root of my repo. Then commit. Then update svn. I can see my code actually committed and updated in svn repo. But the problem is that I don't get any update notice in admin area plugin page. Don't know why.

Comment: I put the new version in 'trunk', the tag folder ("2.1" for version 2.1) and the root folder locally. Then 'commit' from local to repository, selecting all files, with some text in the comment-field-thing before committ. A few minutes later, I get an email from WP that all is well. Then a bit later (not immediately), I do the 'update' check on a test site that has that plugin active. And the new version is 'found'. Note that the update won't be found immediately; I usually wait about an hour.

Comment: Rick you're so right. I found my update notice. It works! Thank you.